# Find the coefficient $c_{-3}$ in the Laurent series $g(z) = \frac{e^{iz}-1}{\cos z-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

The function $\displaystyle g(z) = \frac{e^{iz}-1}{\cos z-1}$ has a Laurent expansion of the form $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_{n}z^{n}$ in the region $2\pi<|z|<4\pi$. Find the coefficient $c_{-3}$.

I am not sure how to proceed with problems of this sort, the only method I know to find Laurent series is to manipulate geometric series. I assume in this case you have to do residue calculations? I would appreciate any input very much, I am studying before an exam in complex analysis.

Comment: You can use plain old high-school division, analogous to the long division of polynomials, but writing terms in greater degree to the right. You know the expansion of top and of bottom, then just divide.

Comment: @Lubin look at the region of convergence - your method cannot be used

Comment: @Lubin, why can you use this method to find the coefficient $c_{3}$ but not $c_{-3}$? It seems hard to find the expansions of the top and the bottom under this region of convergence.

Comment: Sorry, I have *seriously* misread the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(to show that it is a problem you can expect for the exam)

$c_{-3}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{z=c} z^2\frac{e^{iz}-1}{\cos z -1} dz$ for any $2\pi<c<4\pi$. The integrant has possible singularities when $\cos z=1$, i.e. for $z=2\pi n$. Inside the circle these are $z=0,2\pi,-2\pi$. We thus have
$$c_{-3}=\sum_{w\in\{0,2\pi,-2\pi\}}Res_{w}z^2\frac{e^{iz}-1}{\cos z -1}$$
(by the residue theorem}. To compute the residues (use any method you know/like, this is one): $e^{i(x+w)}-1=e^{ix}-1=ix+\dots$, $\cos(x+w)-1=\cos x -1=-x^2/2+\dots$ (for any $w=2\pi n$), hence the residue is $w^2\frac{i}{-1/2}=-2iw^2$. Their sum is $-4i(2\pi)^2=-16i\pi^2$.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the most practical and methodological solution to problems of this sort. I am indebted to you guys.

Comment: the $z^2$ should turn into $(x+w)^2$ so aren't you missing a term in computing each residue?

Comment: @hlcrypto123 no, $z^2=w^2$ at $z=w$, that story with $x$ was used only for the ratio which is of the type $0/0$

Answer (score 2):

Writing $e^{iz} = \cos z + i\sin z$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\frac{e^{iz}-1}{\cos z - 1} &= 1 + i \frac{\sin z}{\cos z - 1}\\
&= 1 + i \frac{2\sin (z/2)\cos(z/2)}{-2\sin^2 (z/2)}\\
&= 1 - i \cot (z/2).
\end{align}$$

Now, for the cotangent, we have the partial fraction decomposition

$$\pi \cot (\pi w) = \frac1w + \sum_{\nu = 1}^\infty \frac{2w}{w^2-\nu^2},$$

from which we obtain

$$\cot (z/2) = \frac2z + \sum_{\nu=1}^\infty \frac{4z}{z^2 - (2\pi\nu)^2}.$$

The only terms with singularities in $\{\lvert z\rvert \leqslant 2\pi \}$ are $\frac2z$ and the term for $\nu = 1$,

$$\frac{4z}{z^2 - (2\pi)^2} = \frac{4}{z}\cdot \frac{1}{1 - \left(\frac{2\pi}{z}\right)^2} = \frac{4}{z}\sum_{\kappa=0}^\infty \left(\frac{2\pi}{z}\right)^{2\kappa}$$

and the coefficient of $z^{-3}$ in that is $4(2\pi)^2 = 16\pi^2$, whence the coefficient $c_{-3}$ in the Laurent series of

$$ \frac{e^{iz}-1}{\cos z - 1}$$

in the annulus $2\pi < \lvert z\rvert < 4\pi$ is $-i16\pi^2$.

Comment: After a false start, this works.

Comment: Thisfinal answer matches the one in my solution manual, so this must be correct. Thank you very much. Apparently this problem is a lot more complicated than I assumed, I did not expect to need to memorize this particular fraction decomposition for cotangent on my exam.

Comment: Just because it matches doesn't necessarily mean it is correct. However, since it matches, I'm pretty confident that I didn't make any mistakes when rescaling the cotangent partial fraction. Everything else is pretty simple. You don't need the partial fraction decomposition, it is sufficient to find the residues in $0, \pm 2\pi$, then you have - since the poles are simple - three principal parts $\frac{a}{z}$, $\frac{b}{z-2\pi}$ and $\frac{c}{z+2\pi}$, then develop these - well, the two nontrivial ones - into Laurent series in the annulus and add the coefficients.

Comment: The nice thing about using the partial fraction of the cotangent is that it makes it very easy to find the principal part of the Laurent series in other annuli.

Comment: Thanks! I'm attempting to solve the problem right now using this method.